# Can you have KL-E-O as a companion?

Tags: fallout-4

When you have hacked KL-E-O from Goodneighbor, can she fast travel with you? Can she be damaged or killed?

I hacked her and she followed me out of Goodneighbor, but when I fast-travelled to another location, she did not come with me. However, when I went back to Sanctuary, she appeared, but then ran off.

Also, while scouting around outside of Goodneighbor, she walked into a super mutant booby trap, which blew off her legs. What happens to her now?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! At the end, you ask "what happens then with her?" What exactly are you wanting to know? Whether she heals, I imagine. Anything else?

Comment: I would be intersted in if you still can trade with her, after hacking.

Comment: Yes as I have mentioned below in the reply to Shaun does she re-spawn back to good neighbours or is she gone from the game period.

Answer (score 1):

With regards to whether she can be killed or not, she can most certainly be destroyed.

Upon death (after 300 HP depleting), she will drop the following:

```
Aluminum x2
Assaultron circuit board
Enhanced targeting card
Fusion cell x11
Nuclear material
Power relay coil
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, so if she is destroyed she is gone from the game for good, or does she re-spawn back at good neighbours.

Comment: @JohnA To be perfectly honest, John - I can't clarify. When I get a chance, I will have to test this for you. But my understanding is that she does not respawn, however, other followers do appear at their previous location.

Comment: Thanks Sean, also in relation to the other part of my original question why does she not fast travel with me to other locations and when I arrived back at Sanctuary she appeared very briefly but then ran off, to where I don't know.

Comment: @JohnA After reloading several saves, I can safely say that she doesn't fast travel with me, either. Why exactly, I do not know but I can clarify that this does seem intended.
Also, when killed, she didn't seem to respawn at all - Again, I'm not sure if that's an issue or intended as I haven't met anyone with the same query.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Fallout 4 Companion Wikia page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Fallout_4_companions) and [KL-E-O's own wikia page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/KL-E-0), Kleo is not an actual companion.

As such, she would not be immortal as actual companions are. I assume hacking her would cause her to behave as any other robot hacked via [Robotics Expert](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Robotics_Expert) would.